# Assumptions for special functions - dirac delta confusion

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I wasn't able to express dirac delta function for the below advection-diffusion-reaction function. (Dirac delta term is useless, either `a3 = 0.9;` or `a3 = 900;` nothing changes.) People use different assumptions for special functions like dirac delta, heavyside etc. I would like to ask that is there a standard/well-accepted assumption for a special function? Or how do you decide on which assumption to be used? (Is it just trial and error?)

For example for the below code which assumption can be used?

Thank you.

````
a1 = 0.1;
a2 = 1.5;
a3 = 0.9;
a4 = 0.4;
xmin = -5;
xmax = +5;
tmax = 50;

sol = NDSolve[{
    D[P[t, x], t] == 
     a1*D[P[t, x], x, x] - a2*D[P[t, x], x] - a3 DiracDelta[x + 1.5] +
       a4 P[t, x],
    P[0, x] == 1.2,
    P[t, xmin] == 1.2,
    P[t, xmax] == 1.2
    },
   P,
   {x, xmin, xmax},
   {t, 0, tmax}
   ];
{
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[P[t, x] /. sol],
  {x, xmin, xmax},
  {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Mesh -> None
  ],
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[P[t, x] /. sol],
  {x, xmin, xmax},
  {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  Contours -> 20]}
```
````

Comment: What do you dislike in the obtained result? The same is produced if `DIracDelta[x+1.5]` is replaced by `eps = 0.01;eps/Pi/(eps^2 + (x + 1.5)^2)`(I don't want to go into math deep  here and now.).``` at the end is superfluous.

Comment: @user64494 Dirac delta term is useless, either ```a3 = 0.9;``` or ```a3 = 900;``` nothing changes.

Comment: The documentation to `DiracDelta` says "Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points:" I leave on the developers'  conscience their wrong interpretation of `DiracDelta` as a measure. Maybe, your formulation of the PDE problem needs in adjustment.

Comment: All  numerical routines sample the available space. If you have a distribution (delta function) that only bothers about a value at a single point (or a region with measure zero), a numerical routine will miss it. Only an analytical integration routine can do this.

Comment: @user64494 Great catch, many thanks! So using an assumption would be better. But again this comes to the same question: which one of these possible assumptions would be the best to pick? Is there a common pick or just try all and pick the best?

Comment: @DanielHuber I was thinking that MMA sets a node to a value of the distrubution and interpolate the surrounding area. OK, get it now. Thank you for the explanation. Is there a numerical difference between "a region with measure zero", and "a dot"?

Comment: In 1D a region of measure zero can be a bunch (even infinite many) dots. In 2D a line in 3D a surface has measure zero, e.t.c. But it can also be much more complicated.

Comment: This is a very confused post, with only one relevant comment from @DanielHuber. To work with point impulses numerically I will suggest approximating as tall thin boxes, or using `WhenEvent` to catch and restart when in proximity of the impulse point(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `NDSolve` to find an approximate solution to your pde, maybe an approximate Dirac Delta will work for you.  Since a true Dirac Delta is an infinitely high, zero width spike with an area of one, I use:

```
dd[x_] = aa E^(-100000 x^2)
```

Solve for `aa` to make the area `1`.

```
Integrate[dd[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1

aa = aa /. Solve[%, aa][[1]]
(*100 Sqrt[10/\[Pi]]*)
```

And we have a numerical approximation to the Dirac Delta.  It's not perfect but you can play with the other parameters if you want.  Then substitute dd for `DiracDelta` in your pde.

```
a1 = 1/10;
a2 = 3/2;
a3 = 9/10;
a4 = 4/10;
xmin = -5;
xmax = +5;
tmax = 50;

sol = NDSolve[{D[P[t, x], t] == 
    a1*D[P[t, x], x, x] - a2*D[P[t, x], x] - a3 dd[x + 3/2] + 
     a4 P[t, x], P[0, x] == 12/10, P[t, xmin] == 12/10, 
   P[t, xmax] == 12/10}, P, {x, xmin, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> \[Infinity], MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000, 
  MaxSteps -> 50000]

GraphicsGrid[{{Plot3D[
    Evaluate[P[t, x] /. sol], {x, xmin, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    Mesh -> None]}, {ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[P[t, x] /. sol], {x, xmin, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    Contours -> 20]}}]
```

[image]

Unlike a true DiracDelta that `NDSolve` misses because it is `0` everywhere but at a point, this one, at least gets recognized by `NDSolve`.